# cannot launch more than 1000 apache processes though maxclients and serverlimits is set to 3000

Tags: apache, process, limit

we have a very strong server (32-cores cpu, 96GB ram) and have apache running in prefork mode. our apache2.conf file includes such settings :

```
<IfModule mpm_prefork_module>
    StartServers         2
    MinSpareServers       5
    MaxSpareServers      20
    ServerLimit      3000
    MaxClients           3000
    MaxRequestsPerChild   1000
</IfModule>
```

the problem is, when our website is under heavy load (when apache process count reaches 1000 to be precise) (or when setting StartServers beyond 1000), apache2 freezes and needs to be restarted. Yet there is still plenty of ram, cpu is underused and apache process count is far beyond maxclients.

My question is, what should i do to allow apache to reach the maxclients configured in the conf file ?

please consider we have already played with /etc/security/limits.conf to set max opened files and nprocs to 5000 (ulimit -a showed these values were well taken into account).

No errors are shown in /var/log/apache2/error.log

Answer (score 0):

Your Apache server may have a compiled in hard limit. To change it you need to recompile your webserver. The default is 200000 which should be high enough - but packages from your linux distribution may differ.

I would rather recommend to get of static file serving from your webserver. Put an nginx or lighttp server in front of your apache. Let it serve static content (images, css, javascript, etc.) and forward dynamic request to your apache.

Comment: thank you for your answer, by the way, do you know the name of the variable to change at compilation time ? to avoid the problem i switched to mod worker+fpm+fast cgi, which limited process count and enhanced speed, reduced cpu and ram.